# Particle in a 2D plane

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Suppose you have a particle on a 2D plane starting at the origin (0, 0). After every second
its position changes either in the x-coordinate or in the y-coordinate by exactly 1 (change
cannot happen in both together). All the four possibilities are equally likely. What is the
probability that the particle comes back to the origin in 6 secs? What is the probability that
the particle comes back to the origin in 8 secs by remaining only in the first quadrant (ie
x, y ≥ 0 for all time)?

My Approach: I have worked out that particle can move in any 4 directions at each second ((0,1),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)) and the final position needs to be (0,0) so there should be backtracking for each move. Not quite able to piece it all together.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Here's a system to maybe get you on the right path. $i$ stands for iteration, or the number of seconds your algorithm is on. The $x$ and $y$ mark different discrete coordinates, while $P(i,x,y)$ is the probability that the particle will be resting on the $(x,y)$ point on iteration $i$.

$i\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ , $\ xy\in \mathbb{Z}$ , $\ P:(i,x,y)\to[0,1]$

$P(0,0,0)=1$

$P(0,x\neq 0,y\neq 0) = 0$

$P(i\neq 0,x,y)=\frac{P(i-1,x-1,y)}{4} + \frac{P(i-1,x,y-1)}{4}+\frac{P(i-1,x+1,y)}{4}+\frac{P(i-1,x,y+1)}{4}$

Comment: Two related questions you should consider: if you flip a fair coin $2n$ times, (1) what is the probability of getting an even number of heads? (2) what is the probability of the number heads being $n$?